# Variable is undefined despite being initialised and passed to function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Not sure where I have gone wrong.

I have the following code which creates a "bubble" on the page every 1-2 seconds, and then destroys each bubble after 6 seconds.

The code generally works fine except for the variable `bubbleID` which shows as `undefined` despite being initialised.

```
function startBubbleMachine(){
        var bubbleID = 1;
        setInterval(function makeBubble(bubbleID){
            var wh = randomInt(143, 50);
            console.log('making bubble number '+bubbleID); // this shows undefined
            $('.wrapper').append('<div class="db-bubble db-bubble-'+bubbleID+'" style="transform:rotate('+randomInt(20, 1)+'deg);left:'+randomInt(100, 1)+'%;width:'+wh+'px;height:'+wh+'px;"></div>');
            killBubble(bubbleID);
            bubbleID++; // this doesn't seem to get used
        }, randomInt(2000, 1000));
    }
```

I'm initialising the `bubbleID` to 1:

```
var bubbleID = 1;
```

I'm then passing the `bubbleID` in the function within the `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function makeBubble(bubbleID){
    ...
});
```

And then I'm incrementing it within that function:

```
bubbleID++;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are not passing anything, since you are not calling the function.

Comment: You're not "passing" the variable, you're *defining* it as a parameter; but no one is ever actually calling the function while actually passing a parameter.

Comment: You don't need to give the parameter to the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're hiding the `var bubbleID` variable by including a like-named parameter in the anonymous function. Get rid of the formal parameter.

```
setInterval(function makeBubble( ){
//                              ^
```

Including that parameter name does not *pass* the variable; it simply says that the function expects a parameter to be passed. There's no need for that, however, because the code in that timer function can "see" the `bubbleID` variable through closure.